# Decomposing vision algorithm into small tasks?

Tags: computer-vision

Can anyone please suggest Partitioning algorithms to partition the vision algorithm (computations or workload) to expose opportunities for parallel execution by decomposing computations into small tasks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a partitioning algorithm necessarily.

In any convolution task, each pixel in the output is independent of any other output pixel. Morphological operations are similarly parallelizable, as well as the Hough Transform.

Using any of these, you could have multiple threads or processes working together. A simple implementation would have a painter that iterates over all pixels, and when a thread is free, it simply takes the current item and advances the iterator (preferably atomically, but it won't break if it isn't atomic), performs the appropriate computation, and writes the result to the output. You don't need to worry about any deadlock or race conditions because the computations are independent of each other.